# SQL Select: How to multiply a column with the count of an ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following (here simplified) database and want to get the month with the highest revenue.

**invoices**
- id
- order_id
- issued (timestamp)

**orders**
- id

**orderItems**
- id
- order_id
- article_id

**articles**
- id
- price

So far I got the following statement:

```
Select articles.price * orderItems.order_id as revenue, Extract(month 
from invoices.issued) 
FROM orderItems
INNER JOIN articles ON orderItems.article_id = articles.id
Inner JOIN orders ON orderItems.order_id = orders.id
Inner JOIN invoices ON orders.id = invoices.order_id
GROUP BY year(issued), month(issued)
Order by revenue DESC Limit 1
```

The calculated revenue is wrong as the price is multiplied with the order_id but should be actually multiplied with the count of the respective order_id. I tried to implement count(orderItems.order_id) but it's not working. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: *but it's not working* is not an error description. Please Show sample data, expected result and result you get

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: That's what I did - invoices.issued is a timestamp from which I get the year and month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT year(i.issued), month(i.issued), SUM(a.price) as revenue, 
FROM orderItems oi JOIN
     articles a
     ON oi.article_id = a.id JOIN
     orders o
     ON oi.order_id = o.id JOIN
     invoices i
     ON o.id = i.order_id
GROUP BY year(i.issued), month(i.issued)
ORDER BY revenue DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In other words, this is a simple aggregation query.  There is no need -- ever -- to multiply by `orderid`.  Also note that this query introduces table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks but you multiply the price with the order_id, which makes no sense. It should be the count of the order_id's multiplied with the price in order to get the revenue.

Comment: @user10826235 . . . Thank you .  I shouldn't have left that in the expression.